# Empty cleaned_data (not missing) from form in validated formset - why?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am iterating over a formset to process each form, but for whatever reason, the forms in the formset have an empty cleaned_data.

This is my view code (fragment):

```
 for dform in directors_formset:
                        dform.is_valid() # has no effect on cleaned_data, returns true
                        ddata = dform.cleaned_data
                        email = ddata['officer_email']
```

**directors_formset has already passed validation. The POST request contains the fields from directors_formset forms. However, ddata == {}. Why?**

Edit: This is the form definition:

```
class OfficerForm(forms.Form):
        is_secretary = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('DIR', 'a director'), ('SEC', 'a secretary')),
                                         label='This officer will be:',
                                         initial='DIR',
                                         widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=SaneRadioField))
        is_corporate = forms.ChoiceField(initial='IND',
                                         label='This officer is:',
                                         choices=(("IND", "an individual"),
                                                  ("EEA", "incorporated in the EEA (including the UK)"),
                                                  ("FOR", "incorporated outside the EEA")),
                                         widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=SaneRadioField))
        given_name = forms.CharField()
        surname = forms.CharField()
        previous_names = forms.CharField()
        residential_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

        company_name = forms.CharField()
        service_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
        officer_email = forms.CharField()

        dob = forms.DateField(label='Date of birth:')
        business_occupation = forms.CharField()
        nationality = forms.CharField()
        country_of_residence = forms.CharField()


        where_registered = forms.CharField()
        registration_number = forms.CharField()
        legal_form = forms.CharField()
        governing_law = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: Can we see the form definition? Have you overridden `clean()`?

Comment: Yuji: Form definition coming up. There's nothing exciting about it.

Comment: Does the formset correctly throw errors if invalid fields are passed in? It should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Yuji - for whatever reason, the error seems to have stopped happening. Very odd. Thanks for helping, though.